# Connecting two IAAS VMs in Azure and accessing c drive from worker role

Tags: azure

Good day.

i have been trying to solve this problem since past couple of days , i have read so many blogs and tried different methods but nothing worked out.

I have a requirement where in i have to access C drive of one IAAS VM (Say A) from another IAAS VM(Say B) through worker role hosted in VM B.

Both VMs may be in same cloud services or may be in different under one subscription or may be in different subscription.

Now the **challenges** i am facing are :

1) I have to Connect these two VMs via worker role this implies i have to write code in Run() method of worker role or define endpoints in worker role in such a way that these when request come from VM B to access C drive of VM A , it should allow.

2.I tried enabled webdevpublishing in VM A and also enabled windows authentication and tried making netwrok drive on VM A so that ican perform  IO operation but network drive didnt create :(

1. This C drive has to be polled continuously in order to check if any file has come or not ?

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Please define steps or code if possible coz i have already followed different suggestions given on web but no luck.

Regards

Comment: You might want to edit your title and question to remove the stuff about urgency. This is a community q&a site. There's no SLA on answer response time.

Comment: Regarding point #1: Not sure what you mean by "connect two VMs via worker role." And Virtual Networks don't use a VPN - they're just a network for vm's to communicate across directly. And Virtual Networks don't span subscriptions or data centers.

Comment: @DavidMakogon : First of all would like to apologize for late reply n would like to say thanks to you for your kind advice, I have removed the word 'Urgent' from the topic and also edited point#1 which defines what do i mean by connect 2 VM via worker role .

Comment: @DavidMakogon :I tried connecting on premise machine to cloud machine or 2 machines in same cloud services via virtual machine but didnt really work for me , may be i had missed something. If there is any working sample code with you for the same, and can share , i would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, there has to be another job\service running on VM-A which is doing the actual job of check for existence of file and reporting the status to a database\storage\queue which the worker role is checking constantly.

Hope this helps.